# Solution for a testing platform

Tags: testing, automated-tests

We are looking for an automated testing software for our web application. We need to come up with a solution or software that our non-it staffs could write test cases as well as the developers.

For example I've run through some of them such as: SmartBear, National Instrument and IBM. Most of these guys are MS Windows based or commercial Linux distros which remove them from our list since we are all Debian based.

Any recommendation or guideline would be much appreciated.

Ps. We don't have any budget limit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have a hard time getting tooling for non-technical testers to build test cases if you limit yourselves to Debian OS for developing and running the tests on. There's no reason you couldn't have a few Windows system to manage your test suites from -- those would run against your web site just fine, regardless of what stack it's hosted on. That would open you up to the tools you mentioned (and Telerik's Test Studio, the tool I help promote).

Those Windows systems could easily be run via whatever virtualization host you prefer, so you wouldn't even need physical systems to deal with that. You could easily share the same source control repository as your devs, too, since nearly every decent SCM has Windows clients.

If you're unwilling to consider having a few Windows boxes around for your testing, then you'll need to have a look at getting all your testers proficient in APIs and frameworks like WebDriver and Robot Framework. The Pages gem from Jeff Morgan (@chzy) in Ruby would be another option, as would Adam Goucher's Saunter (in Python).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Apparently we are going to end up with same solution as you suggested. At the end I still have no clue if we do all this we will have easier testing scheme.

Comment: At the end of the day, regardless of what approach you use, you'll have a learning curve to get up. I've been through this a number of times with different teams. Focus on high-value tests, use lots of communication between devs and testers, and start small. That will be the same regardless of whether you use a framework on Debian or tools inside Windows VMs. Good luck!